# Why is closing my splash screen causing my main window to never display?

Tags: c#, wpf, startup, splash-screen

I'm overriding the OnStartup method as below within my App.xaml.cs.  However, once I added the splash screen closing, my main window is never displayed.  The debugger reaches the main.Show() line but after this is finished executed, the application closes.  Any ideas?

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnStartup(e);

   SplashWindow splash = new SplashWindow();
   splash.Show();

   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
   splash.Close();

   MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
   main.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the default value for [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) is `OnLastWindowClose`, so when you close your splash screen the programm exits.
You can change this by adding the following code after the call to base.OnStartup

```
this.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

If that still doesn't work setting it to `OnExplicitShutdown` might work.

Comment: Yes.  A simple workaround is to call main.Show() before splash.Close()

Answer (score 0):

The [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) method opens a `Window` without waiting for it to close.

You should use the [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method for the app to stop execution until the app closes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to load your main window first but set its visibility property to hidden.  Then launch your splash screen from there and once it closes change the visibility back to visible.